# Gradle install error: Javadoc

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, android-library

I am trying to upload a android library automatically into bintray.

I have this app gradle code:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

ext {
    bintrayRepo = 'maven'
    bintrayName = 'CurrentCenterPositionMap'

    publishedGroupId = 'renatamelo@patriauto.org'
    libraryName = 'CurrentCenterPositionMap'
    artifact = 'current-center-position-map'

    libraryDescription = 'A library to mark the center of a map with moveing animations'

    siteUrl = 'https://github.com/leandroBorgesFerreira/CurrentCenterPositionMap'
    gitUrl = 'https://github.com/leandroBorgesFerreira/CurrentCenterPositionMap.git'

    libraryVersion = '0.8.1'

    developerId = 'leandroBorgesFerreira'
    developerName = 'Leandro Borges Ferreira'
    developerEmail = 'lehen01@gmail.com'

    licenseName = 'The Apache Software License, Version 2.0'
    licenseUrl = 'http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt'
    allLicenses = ["Apache-2.0"]
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

// Place it at the end of the file
apply from: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nuuneoi/JCenter/master/installv1.gradle'
apply from: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nuuneoi/JCenter/master/bintrayv1.gradle'
```

And this project gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.0.4'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.4'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.4.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

But when I run:

```
./gradlew install
```

I get this error:

```
javadoc: error - Illegal package name: "/Users/hinovamobile/Desktop/Leandro/projetinhos/CurrentCenterPositionMap/mapfragmentwrapper/src/main/java/br/com/simplepass/mapfragmentwrapper/MapFragmentWrapper.kt"
1 error
:mapfragmentwrapper:javadoc FAILED
```

So what I am doing wrong? I'm not sure how to fix this error in the Javadoc...

Comment: Add `--debug` flag, it can be useful to understand root of the problem. Also, if possible, show content of `MapFragmentWrapper`

`./gradlew install --debug`

Comment: Also you can try disable javadoc generation https://github.com/novoda/bintray-release/issues/71#issuecomment-224324120 and use KDoc instead

Comment: Hey, thanks. I disabled the javadoc and it worked. But I Will try the --debug later

Answer (score 0):

Try using gradle-fury's scripts to generate javadoc. It does a different version for each android variant, supports umldocs via graphviz, the doc-html folder structure and more. For both Java and Android

Once the scripts are applied to your setup, make the javadocs via
`gradlew install -Pprofile=javadoc`

https://github.com/gradle-fury/gradle-fury

Answer (score 0):

In your main gradle file, add the following lines:

```
tasks.withType(Javadoc).all {
   enabled = false
}
```

Note: this will still normally show the javadocs when you press control + space on top of a class or method.

If you want to read more details check this link: https://github.com/novoda/bintray-release/issues/71